# SQL try catch does not continue after Error

Tags: sql-server-2012, try-catch

We are using SQL Server 2012. We have a script that executes multiple stored procedures and is run by SQL Server Agent. Up until last month when an error occurred the 'Try-Catch' would log the error and continue processing the next stored procedure.

Now when an error is encountered, the error is logged, however, SQL Agent aborts with an error at that point.

We would like processing to continue when an error is encountered, since all of the stored procedures are all standalone.

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
begin try
    INSERT rs_tracking
        SELECT 'RS_Build_Time_Tracker', GETDATE(), Null

    EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_RS_Time_Tracker_SRC]

    SELECT NULL;
end try
begin catch
    INSERT rs_tracking
        SELECT 'RS_Build_Time_Tracker',GETDATE(), ERROR_Message();

    EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_RS_Time_Tracker_SRC]
end catch

begin try
    INSERT rs_tracking
       SELECT 'Build_Client_Rank1',GETDATE(), Null

    EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_Client_Rank1_SRC]

    SELECT NULL;
end try
begin catch
    INSERT rs_tracking
        SELECT 'Build_Client_Rank1',GETDATE(), ERROR_Message();

    EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_Client_Rank1_SRC]
end catch

begin try
INSERT rs_tracking
SELECT 'Build_Client_Rank2',GETDATE(), Null
EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_Client_Rank2_SRC]
  SELECT NULL;
end try
begin catch
INSERT rs_tracking
SELECT 'Build_Client_Rank2',GETDATE(), ERROR_Message();
EXECUTE [EDW].[dbo].[Build_BH_Client_Rank2_SRC]
 end catch
```

Comment: and the error message is...? showing some sql is basically useless without any information on HOW it's failing.

Comment: So probably your catch is also throwing an error?